# How to create a hyperlink to a particular bookmarked spot in an MS Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to share a URL that links to a specific spot in an MS Word document.
It would link to the web version of the document.

My understanding is that you can only link to that from another Word Document.  I'm hoping to share a URL that could be clicked on from any document.

Answer (score 1):

Negative answer : This is not possible.

To publish a document on the internet with bookmarks having URL,
the simplest method is to convert the document to HTML.
You could use
[Save a document as a webpage](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-document-as-a-webpage-d1cf1c33-e854-4f9d-bd51-93f94da0f4e3).

I believe that Google Docs has this feature, see the post
[Create public web URL link to specific section of Google Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575272/create-public-web-url-link-to-specific-section-of-google-doc)